# Codeigniter data from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Each User has multi profiles. once they logged in, they are asked to select a profile,

here is the code for Form to select profile.

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 align ="center" class="panel-title">Select Profiles</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php
                        foreach($resJacs->{'details'} as $key) {
                            echo form_open('selectaccess', array(
                                'class' => 'form-group',
                                'role' => 'form'
                            ));
                            echo form_submit(array(
                                'value' => $key->profile_name,
                                'name' => $key->profile_type,
                                'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block'
                            ));
                            echo form_close();
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when user selects the profile profile id is passed to session for later use. here is the code for "selectaccess",

```
    public function SelectAccess() {
    $sess_data = array(
        'id' => $this->session->userdata['is_logged_in']['id'],
        'prfid' => $this->input->post('')
    );

    print_r($sess_data);
}
```

how can i prfid as mentioned in selectaccess method.

Comment: what is prfid ??

Comment: You are assigning the name attribute for submit button dynamically, `'name' => $key->profile_type`. If you do that, you cannot retrieve the value at the server side.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS could you suggest me a way.

Comment: Remove quotes from `$this->input->post()`.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: @Tpojka it works fine, but need some improvement in the code. when i retrieve `$this->input->post()` in controller it echo an array format, how can i get array index of the post in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give an example, maybe this can help u :

I am use pure html .

```
<form action="SelectAccess/<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="text" name="name">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
function SelectAccess($val='') {
$input = $this->input->post('name');
$_SESSION['whatever'] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to know the name of the field in order to get the value at the controller. But you are dynamically creating the field names so that gets tricky.

Fortunately you are only posting one input so `$_POST` should have only one item. The way your view is written the value of `$_POST[0]` will be provided by `$key->profile_name`. Hopefully, that value is what you are looking for.

```
public function SelectAccess() {
{
    $sess_data = array(
        'id' => $this->session->userdata['is_logged_in']['id'],
        'prfid' => isset($_POST[0])) ? $_POST[0] : NULL;
    );
}
```

Comment: "its Not working" doesn't help me help you. What does "Not working" mean? I made an edit to the answer. Maybe that will help you understand what value is being posted.